# Netbeans 8.0.2 Remove From Project broken, how to make it work?

Tags: netbeans

Symptoms: Large C++ project; I have an extraneous .cpp file in a common directory, listed in a logical subfolder, that I want to remove from the project but not delete on the disk.  I right-click on the filename in the projects directory, and select Remove From Project in the popup menu.  The name of the file disappears from the Project listing.

However, the .o and .o.d files are not erased from disk; neither is the file listing removed from the project's various netbeans config and Makefiles, etc.

Round 1:  Hammer-button recompile.  The old .o is still included, and compile fails with its unmet dependencies.

Round 2:  Broom-button erase all .o's and recompile.  It's still included.

Same effect if I Remove a folder.

Again:  File does not appear in the Project table of contents, but is still quietly bound in, causing bloat and unneeded dependencies.

I'm having to go in and update each config and Makefile etc. manually.  Is this a known bug?  Any workarounds?